# Where can I find examples of Takeuchi Information Criterion (TIC) at work?

Tags: aic, fisher-information

I have been looking for examples of the TIC and couldn't find any. In particular I would like to know how exactly do you estimate the penalty term in TIC. That term consists of, as I found it somewhere, score function and Fisher information.
Are there any online resources where I can find that?

Comment: You found something online but you don't share it with us....

Comment: Sorry for that nick. As i am not even sure if it is true i didn't want to confuse anyone with that. It was only sort of a guideline towards what i am looking for.

Comment: I don't know anything about TIC; I'm just trying to prod you into asking a better question. But people who know something can't even tell you how reliable your source if you won't reveal it.

Comment: i got it. [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.1724&rep=rep1&type=pdf) thats the source

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example found from the book [Information Criteria and Statistical Modeling](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387718866) (pages 61-64) with my own minor changes and corrections to the presentation:

> $\text{TIC}$ for normal model

Let data samples $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ be generated from a true
distribution $g(x)$. We aim to estimate 
$g(x)$ by using a normal model:

$$f(x|\mu,\sigma^2) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).\hspace{3cm}(1)$$

We estimate the parameters $\mu, \sigma^2$ with maximum likelihood 
(which is required by $\text{TIC}$ to my understanding), so our estimator model is:

$$f(x|\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}^2) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat{\sigma}^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\hat{\mu})^2}{2\hat{\sigma}^2}\right),$$

where $\hat{\mu}=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and 
$\hat{\sigma}^2=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\hat{\mu})^2$.

The $\text{TIC}$ for the given model 
$f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)$ (where $\boldsymbol\theta =(\mu, \sigma^2)$ now) is defined as:

$$\text{TIC}=-2\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(x_i|\boldsymbol\theta) + 
2\text{tr}(I(\boldsymbol\theta)J(\boldsymbol\theta)^{-1}),$$

where $b=\text{tr}(I(\boldsymbol\theta)J(\boldsymbol\theta)^{-1})$ 
is the bias term and the $d\times d$ ($d$ is dimensionality of the 
parameter vector, here we have $d=2$) matrices $I(\boldsymbol\theta)$ and 
$J(\boldsymbol\theta)$ are defined as:

$$I(\boldsymbol\theta)=E_g \left[\frac{\partial\log 
f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial \boldsymbol\theta}\frac{\partial\log 
f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial 
\boldsymbol\theta^T}\biggr\rvert_{\boldsymbol\theta=\boldsymbol\theta}\right],\hspace{2cm}(2)$$

$$J(\boldsymbol\theta)=-E_g \left[\frac{\partial^2 \log 
f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta 
\partial\boldsymbol\theta^T}\biggr\rvert_{\boldsymbol\theta=\boldsymbol\theta}\right].\hspace{4cm}(3)$$

In the above, tr$(\cdot)$ stands for matrix trace and $E_g$ is 
expectation with respect to distribution $g(x)$. Lets now proceed to calculate the matrices $I(\boldsymbol\theta)$ and $J(\boldsymbol\theta)$ given our model $f(x|\mu,\sigma^2)$ in $(1)$. First, we need to calculate the log-likelihood function:

$$\log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi\sigma^2\right)-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$

The partial derivatives of the log-likelihood function are:

$$\frac{\partial \log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu}=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2},\hspace{1cm}\frac{\partial \log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\sigma^2}=-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^4}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 \log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu^2}=-\frac{1}{\sigma^2},\hspace{1cm}\frac{\partial^2 \log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial(\sigma^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^6}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 \log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu\partial \sigma^2}=\frac{\partial^2 \log f(x|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\sigma^2\partial\mu}=-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^4}.$$

We therefore have the corresponding $2\times 2$ matrices:

$$\begin{aligned}I(\boldsymbol\theta)&=E_g\left[\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu} \\
\frac{\partial \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\sigma^2}  
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu} &
\frac{\partial \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\sigma^2}  
\end{pmatrix}\right]\\ &=E_g\left[\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma^2} \\
-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^4} 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma^2} &
-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^4}
\end{pmatrix}\right] \\ &=E_g\left[\begin{matrix} 
\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^4} & -\frac{x-\mu}{2\sigma^4}+\frac{(X-\mu)^3}{2\sigma^6} \\
-\frac{X-\mu}{2\sigma^4}+\frac{(X-\mu)^3}{2\sigma^6} & \frac{1}{4\sigma^4}-\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^6}+\frac{(X-\mu)^4}{4\sigma^8}
\end{matrix}\right] \\ &=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} & \frac{\mu_3}{2\sigma^6} \\
\frac{\mu_3}{2\sigma^6} & \frac{\mu_4}{4\sigma^8}-\frac{1}{4\sigma^4}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}J(\boldsymbol\theta) &= -E_g\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\mu\partial\sigma^2} \\ \frac{\partial^2 \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\sigma^2\partial\mu} & \frac{\partial^2 \log f(X|\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial(\sigma^2)^2}\end{bmatrix} \\ &= E_g\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sigma^2} & \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma^4} \\ \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma^4} & \frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^6}-\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}\end{bmatrix}\\ &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sigma^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2\sigma^4}\end{bmatrix},\end{aligned}$$

where $\mu_j=E_g\left[(X-\mu)^j\right]$ is the $j$th-order centralized moment. We then have:

$$I(\boldsymbol\theta)J(\boldsymbol\theta)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} & \frac{\mu_3}{2\sigma^6} \\
\frac{\mu_3}{2\sigma^6} & \frac{\mu_4}{4\sigma^8}-\frac{1}{4\sigma^4}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\sigma^4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{\mu_ 3}{\sigma^2}\\ \frac{\mu_3}{2\sigma^4} & \frac{\mu_4}{2\sigma^4}-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix},$$

and therefore the bias term is:

$$b=\text{tr}\left(I(\boldsymbol\theta)J(\boldsymbol\theta)^{-1}\right) = 1 + \frac{\mu_4}{2\sigma^4}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}\right).\hspace{2cm}(4)$$

Thus, by now plugging in the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}=(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma}^2)$, we get the estimator for the bias term:

$$\hat{b}=\text{tr}\left(I(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta})J(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta})^{-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{\hat{\mu}_4}{\hat{\sigma}^4}\right),$$

where $\hat{\sigma}^4 = (\hat{\sigma}^2)^2$ and $\hat{\mu}_4=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\hat{\mu})^4$. It then follows that the $\text{TIC}$ in this example is:

> $$\begin{aligned}\text{TIC} &= -2\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(x_i|\hat{\mu},
>  \hat{\sigma}^2) + 
>  2\left(\frac12+\frac{\hat{\mu}_4}{2\hat{\sigma}^4}\right) \\ &=
>  -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi\hat{\sigma}^2)-\frac{n}{2} + 2\left(\frac12+\frac{\hat{\mu}_4}{2\hat{\sigma}^4}\right).\end{aligned}$$

Note also, that if there exists $\boldsymbol\theta_0$ such that $f(x|\theta_0)=g(x)$, then $g(x)$ is a normal distribution and we have $\mu_3 = 0, \mu_4=3\sigma^4$. We then have in $(4)$ that:

$$b=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3\sigma^4}{2\sigma^4}=2,$$

in which case, the $\text{TIC}$ becomes $\text{AIC}$ (Akaike information criterion) :

> $$\begin{aligned}\text{AIC} &= -2\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(x_i|\hat{\mu},
>  \hat{\sigma}^2) +  2\times 2 \\ &=
>  -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi\hat{\sigma}^2)-\frac{n}{2} + 4.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: For the rest of us who aren't inclined to spend 107,09 € to understand your response, could you elaborate more on the contents of those pages? Maybe provide a brief synopsis on the model described and how TIC fits in?

Comment: @DavidMarx sure, I can provide the example here, will take me little bit of time.

Comment: @DavidMarx hi, added example finally.